# regex multiple instances of word between quotes (sql)

Tags: php, sql, regex, pcre

im trying to match VALUES between quotes, since i have problem with word VALUES  in strings when converting. The sample string is

```
INSERT INTO lt VALUES (2, '2007-08-06', 10000.00, 'startVALUES VALUE\'S startVALUESend VALUESend', NULL);
```

I'm using

```
(\'.*?(?:\\').*?(values).*?\')
```

Here is [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/EHrwsz/2) demo.

I managed to focus on text between quotes, not matching escaped ones, but i cant match all VALUES, only one gets captured. Could you help catch start(VALUES) and (VALUES)end

my pg2mysql converter replaces VALUES inside quotes with additional inserts so I want to capture possible values strings inside quotes and do some workaround.

Comment: Show us the code, sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, no links/images please.

Comment: Are you just trying to remove all occurrences of `VALUES` inside `'...'` substrings that may contain escaped single quotes?

Comment: Please provide the expected output in the question, and explain why you expect that value

Comment: Help us help you. What do you want the sting to turn into?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate values before adding them to insert statement-

```
$column1 = "startVALUES VALUES startVALUESend VALUESend";
$column1 = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',str_replace('VALUES','',$column1));
```

If string comes with `VALUE\'s` then you need to handle it separately.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Why are you using a different input string? OP has `INSERT INTO lt VALUES (2, '2007-08-06', 10000.00, 'startVALUES VALUE\'S startVALUESend VALUESend', NULL);`.

Comment: Because for security reason we treat each value of this insert statement independently and here he can separately process individual column values. So this is the right place where he can perform all filtration process